# Did Adrian know Joe Doucett is going to have sex with Marie?

Tags: plot-explanation, oldboy-2013

In the *Oldboy* (2013) movie, when Joe Doucett was having sex with Marie, they did not 
know that Adrian was filming them. Later on the show, Adrian shows the sex 
footage to Joe Doucett in order to upset him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Joe had been locked in solitary for a couple of decades. If Adrian had been grooming Marie to be attracted to a certain kind of man, the right ingredients would be there for some type of chemistry. As far as the video, He was probably keeping tabs on Marie her entire life. Every place she ever lived was probably wired. Plus, there is the issue of hypnosis like in the original film. If it was done to Joe, it was probably also done to Mia/Marie to get her to fall for joe. This would probably make the choice of hotel rooms more than coincidental, also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was part of his plan all along. Their initial meeting was planned. I don't know about 2013 but in the manga and original the hero was hynpotized at night to be sexually attracted to have sex with each other.